# Catalog architecture for parts and sets

Tags: catalog, products-management, bundle, custom-product-type

I have experience creating Magento websites, and have a client with a complex product catalog that I'm not sure how to map to Magento product types.

The client sells furniture.

A product for sale may be composed of multiple 'parts'.  For example, a bed would be composed of a headboard, footboard, and slats.  Each one of those three would have its own inventory tracking and shipping needs, but they are not sold separately.

There are also products that are sets.  Continuing our example, the bed may be sold in a bedroom set, including night tables and a dresser.

I'm thinking simple, not visible products for the 'parts', but I don't see the right product type to use for the bed-level.  With both grouped or bundled products, the bed couldn't be included within the higher level bedroom set.

What catalog architecture should I use here?

Comment: There is no solution for what you need.

I recommend to implement the possibility to have bundled products in bundled products.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating 2 bundled products. One is the bed with it's parts, one is the whole bedroom set with the same parts plus the extra items like a nightstand.

This will require some more administration by your client but won't require any code changes and in my opinion that's a good trade off. Changing the way bundled products work might have negative side effects in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it should be possible to configure the bed, but the sets are fixed as groups of one configurable bed along with simple products? In this case, you could do it as follows:

1. Bed as bundle product
2. Night table and dresser as simple products (not visible individually)
3. Group product "Make it a set" consisting of night table and dresser (possibly multiple combinations as one group product each)
4. Add group product(s) as related product(s) to bed

Now you can configure your bed and either buy it as is or "make it a set" together with night table and dresser. Special prices for the sets could be possible with shopping cart price rules.

Depending on how you want to present your sets this will need some changes in the interface for related products but at least the solution does not need a new or changed product type.